# change background color of UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone

I am new in xcode, so help me out please. how can we change background color to UIImagePickerController? i want to change it to black color?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) You cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you change the background color of a view (UIView) by setting its backgroundColor variable to a UIColor object: self.view = [UIColor blackColor];

However, the UIImagePickerController is not intended to be modified. If you do, your app will be rejected from the app store.

A solution would be to use the [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) implementation of an image picker: TTThumbsViewController, which you can modify to your hearts content.